# Need to Modifify the navigation method in order to have more navigation than one

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My navigation method in the base abstract class

```
public abstract void Navigate(SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e); '
```

In one of my View classes, I need to have more than one navigation when some button clicked or tapped. using my navigate function only I can use for one navigation I need to improve the navigate method to have improved so it can use for multiple navigations. I am a little clueless here what should I do do a relay command or use generic. what I need to change in order to use this method for multiple navigation purposes

```
 private void JournalSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e?.SelectedItem == null) return;
        JournalGroupList.SelectedItem = null;
        Navigate(e);
    }

    public override async void Navigate(SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        JournalHistoryViewPage journalHistoryViewPage = App.Container.Resolve<JournalHistoryViewPage>();
        journalHistoryViewPage.BaseViewModel.JournalGroup = e.SelectedItem as JournalGroup;
        journalHistoryViewPage.BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient = BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(journalHistoryViewPage, true);
    }

  private async void VitalSigns_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var vitalSignsViewPage = App.Container.Resolve<VitalSignsViewPage>();
        vitalSignsViewPage.BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient = BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(vitalSignsViewPage, true);
    }
```

As I used Navigate Function in journalselected I also need it to use for VitalSigns_tapped. In here I feel like I have duplicated the code and did not use the method properly

Comment: why don't you just use a switch statement in your Navigate method to determine which page to load?

Comment: You mean in navigate method in switch what parameter i need to used to separate them

Comment: e.SelectedItem - presumably that contains the selected page?  Or you could just pass a string instead

Comment: Can you provide a example i relly  did not get the point

Comment: @ish1104 do you really need to use several navigations? Why don't you use another type of page, e.g. PopupPage ot ModalPage?

Comment: Its a final year project supervisor specially asked to update navigate function in order to have multiple navigations.says make navigate function more generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a  page to `Navigate function` will make navigate function more generic. Next time you want to navigate a new page, just pass a new page to it.

```
    private void JournalSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e?.SelectedItem == null) return;
        JournalGroupList.SelectedItem = null;

        JournalHistoryViewPage journalHistoryViewPage = App.Container.Resolve<JournalHistoryViewPage>();
        journalHistoryViewPage.BaseViewModel.JournalGroup = e.SelectedItem as JournalGroup;
        journalHistoryViewPage.BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient = BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient;

        Navigate(journalHistoryViewPage);
    }

    private async void VitalSigns_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var vitalSignsViewPage = App.Container.Resolve<VitalSignsViewPage>();
        vitalSignsViewPage.BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient = BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient;

        Navigate(vitalSignsViewPage);
    }

    public override async void Navigate(Page  page)
    {        
        await Navigation.PushAsync(page, true);
    }
```

If every page has a `BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient` and has the **same** value, you can also combine it into Navigate function, for example:

```
public override async void Navigate(Page  page)
    {        
        page.BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient = BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(page, true);
    }
```